# Trying to Read text line by line and write into output file each line in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to read data from a text file (line by line) and I want to write into output file the lines I read from the flies.

Here is how I programmed my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class read {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String input = null;
        input = readFile();
        writeFile(input);

    }
    public static void writeFile(String in)
    {
        String fileName = "output.txt";
    //String payload = null;
     try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
        BufferedWriter bw =new BufferedWriter(fw);  
        bw.write(in);                       
        System.out.println("Received "+in.length()+" bytes: ");  
        bw.close();
     }
     catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error writing to file '"+ fileName + "'");
     }

    }


    public static String readFile()
    {
        String fileName = "temp.txt";
        String line = null;
        String Sentence = null;
        try {            
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //Sentence += line+'\n';
            Sentence = line +'\n';
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println("Sending file "+fileName);
        return Sentence;
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'"); 
            return null;
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");   
            return null;
        // Or we could just do this: 
        // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

text file:
I returned##% from the City about three o'clock on that 
May afternoon pretty well disgusted with life. 
I had been three months in the Old Country, and was 
fed up with it.

Output:
The read method reads first line from the text file and writes that line into output file...

I am new in programming and would really appreciate help!

Answer (score 0):

For creating the output file, try this:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filename, "UTF-8");
writer.println(in);
writer.close();
```

When you read from the file you should append the lines to your original variables by doing

```
Sentence += line+'\n';
```